# CASL - Vue 3 - Element not showing for role

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, casl

I am having a bit of a challenge implementing CASL in my app.

I have created the following composable **useAppAbility** ("hook") that defines all the rules:

```js
import { AbilityBuilder, createMongoAbility, subject } from "@casl/ability";
import { useAbility } from "@casl/vue";

const service = {};
const user = {};
const subscription = {};
const invoice = {};
const account = {};

const ability = createMongoAbility();

const ROLES = ["admin", "account_owner", "beneficiary", "super_admin"];

const defineAbilityFor = (role: Object) => {
  const { can, rules } = new AbilityBuilder(createMongoAbility);
  const is = (r: string) => {
    return ROLES.indexOf(r) >= ROLES.indexOf(role);
  };

  if (is("admin")) {
    can("add", subject("User", user));
    can("remove", subject("User", user));
  }

  return ability.update(rules);
};

export { defineAbilityFor, ability, subject };
export const useAppAbility = () => useAbility();
```

Added the plugin to the **main.ts**:

```js
import { ability } from "@/composables/useAppAbility";
import { abilitiesPlugin } from "@casl/vue";
createApp(App)
  .use(abilitiesPlugin, ability, {
    useGlobalProperties: true,
  })
//stuff
.mount("#app");
```

And then, I found that using the beforeEach hook in the router and passing in the user before each route was the simplest way to deal with page load and SPA routing.
I have therefore added the following to my **router/index.ts**:

```js
import { ability, defineAbilityFor } from "@/composables/useAppAbility";
import useAuth from "@/composables/useAuth";

const {
  getUserByClaims,
} = useAuth();
// routes
router.beforeEach(async (to, _from, next) => {
  defineAbilityFor(getUserByClaims.value.roles)
})
```

At this stage I can verify that the user is being passed properly to the `defineAbilityFor` function and when using the `ability.on("update")` hook to log the rules object, I have the following output:
[image]

Which seems to confirm that the rules for this user are built and updated correctly?

However, when trying to display a button for the said admin in a component, the button does not show.

MyComponent.vue:

```html
<script setup lang="ts">
import { useAppAbility, subject } from "@/composables/useAppAbility";
const { can } = useAppAbility();
</script>
<template>
<div v-if="can('add', subject('User', {}))">TEST FOR CASL</div> <!-- DOES NOT SHOW-->
</template>
```

Not sure where to go from there, any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You will need to use the subject helper everywhere `v-if="can('add', subject('User',{}))"`, or don't use it like so : `if (is("admin")) {
    can("add", "User");
    can("remove", "User");
  }`

Comment: Hi @Lk77, good point, thanks. I have updated the code in my template with the subject helper, but this is still not working.  I will update my question to reflect these changes.